# How to write Algorithms in boxes

Tags: algorithms

I am currently writing an algorithm. I want to write an algorithm given below. Till now I have been able to do this much only.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tabularx,lipsum,environ,amsmath,amssymb}
%\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\usepackage{cleveref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref
\crefname{Lemma}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,lipsum,environ,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{rr}
\author{shi }
\date{October 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}


\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\textbf{Input} : $G^{'}$\;
\textbf{Decide} : Yes or No  \\~\\

 \caption{ \textsc{Algorithm} }
\end{algorithm}
 \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Question:** How to close the boundaries from the left side and right side of the algorithm?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301) and thanks for including a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
```

use

```
\usepackage[boxruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
```

This yields:

[image]